# 3unsaved transient instance when getting an object in grails

Tags: grails

I am getting an unsaved transient instance exception when getting an object.

Here's the code:

```
  String string = "name1|name2"
  string.split("[|]").each {
                           if (it) {
                                    println it
                                    Product p = Product.findByName(it.toUpperCase()).save()
                                    if(p) {
                                        Components c =  new Components(product: p).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
                                        st.addToComponents(c)
                                    }

                                }
                            }
```

Here's the exception

```
 | Error org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Product; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Product
```

I don't understand how getting an object can cause this. I have checked the object is not in the database. But my FailOnError:true is not giving any errors on save.

Comment: Can you add more code? Is this code executed in a controller or in a service? What is "it"? Are you iterating a list of domain objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
Product p = Product.findByName(it.toUpperCase()).save()
```

has no sense. Try to remove `save()`:

```
Product p = Product.findByName(it.toUpperCase())
```

Also, try to do `c.validate()` before you `save()` that instance. It may have validation errors

Comment: That was for testing originally it didn't have the ,save() and gave the same error.

Comment: Try to validate() your "c" instance before saving

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the hibernate session not flushing the batch to the database. Which makes this post redundant. So I have opened another thread.